# Alternative approach to help user if he forgets his password and security answer in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using `Asp.Net Forms Authentication` , I am storing passwords in `Hashed` format and I do require a `Question` and `Answer`.My question is that what happens if a user forgets his `security question's` answer and his `password`.So without that I wont be able to generate a random `password`.What happens in such case , is the user left with only option to create a new account .Or should I link a table to store his question and answer in plain text and then pass the answer while resetting the password.I am sure you guys might have seen this a lot of times.How can I solve this.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask this on [security.se]

Comment: look into the membership class, this class can help to automate this stuff for you. for example, in one of my systems if the password is forgotten they answer their secret question and the system emails them their password

Comment: @peroija what happens if they dont know the answer also

Comment: @AakashM I dont think so , this question is suitable for this site as well

Comment: You should read [The Definitive Guide To Forms based Website Authentication - Don't. Never ever use 'secret questions'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication).

Comment: @ErikPhilips , thanks I will read it.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should the user not know his/her question/answer you can always have the system send an email with a link to a password recovery page. here you could ask them questions that they SHOULD know the answer to based on more senstive information that they entered when they created the account (their name, DOB, etc.)

**Be warned** that this should only be done if your site is nothing like a bank site and only if it is a low security site. Otherwise follow Walter's and AakashM's advice and post on the security forum.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this question is not really a programming question, and more of a security design question and would be better answered in http://security.stackexchange.com .

That being said, if the security needs of your website are relatively low (not bank level security), I think it's sufficient to email a new password to the email address that you have on file for the user. If the user is able to authenticate with their email provider, then they have proven that they are themselves (assuming their email account hasn't been compromised). This is how many web sites operate.

Answer (score 0):

You should look over the following link I think it will help you. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs